# Resize image using PHP from an external image URL

Tags: php, css, image-processing

I'm creating a web app that allows users to specify an image url to display an image along with their submission.

To avoid some potentially large images and odd sizes, i'd like to use PHP to limit/resize the image before it gets output to the browser (I know i could use max-width in CSS but this is unnecessary downloading)

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP resize and upload an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608586/php-resize-and-upload-an-image)

Comment: If CSS is unnecessary downloading, wouldn't you consider PHP doing the download unnecessary as well? Or what would make a difference for you and why?

Comment: I'd rather resize it server side than client side, thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a library named `GD`. It's fairly easy to check the size of an image with the [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete code for it with 2 module/extensions: http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/05/07/resizing-images-in-php-with-gd-and-imagick/

a comparison of them can be found here: http://dreamfall.blogspot.com/2008/02/php-benchmarks-gd-vs-imagemagick.html which may be of use if you want optimize features.